# How to use R1C1 formatted text in a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-r1c1-notation

In order to get dynamic formulas to develop through VBA, I had to use INDIRECT(ADDRESS(. I am now stuck with several dozen formulas that look like this:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(37,10),1)*(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(37,7),1)+(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(69,10),1)*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(77,10),1))+(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(70,10),1)*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(78,10),1))+(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(71,10),1)*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(79,10),1))+(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(72,10),1)*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(80,10),1))+(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(73,10),1)*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(81,10),1))+(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(74,10),1)*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(82,10),1))+(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(75,10),1)*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(83,10),1)))
```

I cannot use these formulas with Solver because it is too much for Solver. When I manually translate the formulas to "A1" format, then Solver works. I need to automate the translation because this is meant to be a template.

I was hoping that replacing "INDIRECT(ADDRESS" with "Cells" might work. No luck. Is there an expression I can use that can replace "INDIRECT(ADDRESS" that will read the R1C1 format? Or do you have a better solution?

Thanks!

```
 r = 0
    Do Until r = 6
        i = 0
        Do Until i = DCShipFrom
        Cells(70 + r, 7 + DCShipFrom + i).Select
        Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & 67 & "," & 7 + DCShipFrom + i & "),1)<=" & "INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & 70 + r & "," & 6 & "),1)," & "INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & 67 & "," & 7 + DCShipFrom + i & "),1)>" & "INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & 69 + r & "," & 6 & "),1)),1,0)"
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    r = r + 1
    Loop
    enter code here
```

Comment: I don't see how this is dynamic as `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(37,10),1)*...` = `$J$31*...`

Comment: I had to use INDIRECT(ADDRESS in my VBA to create the dynamic equations. The long formula is the result. I need the long formula to be simplified so Solver can work.

Comment: That is the point I do not see how this is dynamic. `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(37,10),1)` will always refer to $J$31 that is not dynamic.  So we are missing some information.  please include the actual code.

Comment: I think I am miscommunicating. I no longer need anything to be dynamic because the VBA did it for me. Now I am stuck with formulas like above. Do you know of a way to simplify only the formula so Solver can use it?

Comment: okay show the vba that creates the formula

Comment: The code has been added, but that is not my question. The formulas are done and they work, I just need the finished formulas simplified.

Comment: Not in the comments, please.  Put the code in the original post using [edit]

Comment: Yes the problem is with how you assume r1c1 formulas work.  You do not need the INDIRECT(ADDRESS()) to make it dynamic.  You just need to create a simple formula dynamically.

Comment: *I had to use INDIRECT(ADDRESS in my VBA to create the dynamic equations.* So what does =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(37,10) give you that =INDIRECT($J$37 doesn't? Also note that INDIRECT is often a poor choice compared to functions such as CHOOSE, INDEX (reference version) or other approaches. Especilaly when used in VBA, as it only takes someone to add or remove rows or columns and suddenly your formulas are pointing to the wrong place. Suggest you lodge a new question that addresses the cause of your issue (bad formula choice) rather than the symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it makes the formulas dynamic, but much simpler:

```
For r = 0 To 6
    For i = 0 To DCShipFrom
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(70 + r, 7 + DCShipFrom + i).Formula = "=IF(AND(" & .Cells(67, 7 + DCShipFrom + i).Address(0, 0) & "<=" & .Cells(70 + r, 6).Address(0, 0) & "," & .Cells(67, 7 + DCShipFrom + i).Address & " >" & .Cells(69 + r, 6).Address & "),1,0)"
        End With
    Next i
next r
```

Or if you want R1C1:

```
For r = 0 To 6
    For i = 0 To DCShipFrom
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(70 + r, 7 + DCShipFrom + i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(R" & 67 & "C" & 7 + DCShipFrom + i & " <= R" & 70 + r & "C" & 6 & ",R" & 67 & "C" & 7 + DCShipFrom + i & " > R" & 69 + r & "C" & 6 & "),1,0)"
        End With
    Next i
Next r
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Scott! It took me a while to reply because I was getting an error. I added a closing ) right before the ,1 at the end.  This should solve my problem. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ShNBl84 yup missed that.  sorry.  It is in there now.  Glad to help.  Sometime it is better to get to the root than to try and change the end result.

Answer (score 0):

With `ADDRESS(37, 10)` returning $J$37 use,

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(37, 10), 1)  'or INDIRECT(ADDRESS(37,10)) since xlA1 is default
```

With `ADDRESS(37, 10, 1, 0)` returning R37C10 use,

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(37, 10, 1, 0), 0)  'the zeroes denote xlR1C1 addressing
```

You might want to consider one of the following,

```
INDEX($J:$J, 37)
INDEX($A:$Z, 37, 10)
```

INDEX is non-volatile. Both INDIRECT and ADDRESS are volatile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDIRECT with R1C1 format by adding ,FALSE at the end of your indirect statement and to make it dynamic you make the row and column variables e.g.

```
INDIRECT("R" & myrow & "C" & mycol,FALSE)
```